# McNemar's test for paired binary data

Tags: r, statistics, binary-data

I have some data encoded with the number 0,1,2 before and after treatment.  0 - No improvement, 1- Improvement, 2-Moderate improvement. The data obtained from patient's heart. They divided the heart into 16 parts and they encoded each part with either 0,1 or 2.

The data look as below.

[image]

I want to run a test to check if there is a statistical significance before and after treatment.

I read that McNemar's test is for paired binary data but I don't know if it's the best one for my case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your question might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as there are more stats experts around there that can help you

Comment: also it will be easier to help you if you post data here in a way that we can easily copy and paste it into R - either as text or output from `dput`

Comment: How can I do that? Because I tried to put them as text but I didn't manage to.

Comment: I don't think McNemar's test will work here because you have ordinal outcome data (no improvement, moderate improvement, improvement) instead of binary outcome data (meaning there can only be two possible responses, e.g. improved/didn't improve). It looks like you have a complete block design - maybe consider Friedman's test.